# What is the extent of Haki's power?

Tags: one-piece

I know it allows you to defeat logia users and gives your hits more strenth, but is it the only thing it can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 main types of haki

Kenbunshoku: Allows prediction and to sense people hiding

Busoshoku: Armament strengthens attack and defense penetrates logia types

Haoshoku: King's haki, breaks the will of weaker people rendering them unable to function.

As for the limits of each we cannot judge that at this time. The concept of haki didn't become public knowledge until the new world came into the scene.

We do know 2 things so far. The first is from Zoro vs Pica and Tra vs Vergo. If one person's haki is stronger than another's it will allow you to penetrate it.

The second is from Luffy vs Doflamingo and that's that haki can run out and a user won't be able to use it for awhile once it does. How long and how much is still pretty unclear.

Comment: @trafalgarlaw    If my answer solves your question please click the check-mark so that it gets accepted and removed from the open queue.

Comment: Like what I just did?

Comment: @trafalgarlaw yup that's perfect. Thank you.

Comment: There's four, you forgot the shield one.

Comment: No the shield one is part of buso. It augments attack and defense

Comment: Busoshoku also has another application called "hardening". That's Buso Koka. The one where objects become black. The invisible shield/armour, is just normal Busoshoku.  Shanks KIng's Haki also damaged Whitebeard's ship.

Comment: @TobiAlafin busoshoku is always blackened in the new world. The blackening only serves for visual distinction to the reader  and due to the main characters being exposed to and understanding what Haki is now. It's similar to nen from hunter x hunter where it was invisible until learned then you can see it. Also hardening translates roughly into armament which is what I was describing.

Comment: This is not true. Sabaody arc. Luffy used a Haki jet pistol on the Pacifista. It wasn't blackened.